# Auxochrome groups and red shift

Tags: quantum-chemistry, spectroscopy, absorption

Wikipedia states that "An auxochrome is known as a compound that produces a batochromic shift, also known as a red shift because it increases the absorption wavelength, thus approaching infrared light."
That said, let us consider ethylene (chromophore group) and vinyl chloride (chromophore group to which we have added the auxochrome Cl).  The addition of the auxochrome produces a red shift, as written in the definition above. But what transition does this Red shift refer to?
Does it refer to the π-π* transition, whereby this means that, as a result of the addition of chlorine, there is a reduction in the energy gap between the π orbitals, so the absorption band corresponding to this transition shifts to higher wavelengths?

Or does the Red shift refer to the fact that new non-bonding orbitals are formed, due to the addition of chlorine, so that a new absorption band at higher lambdas is generated, corresponding to the n-π* transition, and thus a reduction in the energy gap between HOMO and LUMO (which are, respectively, n and π*) is observed?

Comment: Adding Cl is essentially no different to the H atom that it replaces, except that the orbital energy may be lowered and so affecting the $\pi-\pi^*$ energy gap. You can observe $n-\pi^*$ transitions in molecule such as acetone or formaldehyde where there are lone pairs not involved in bonding.

Comment: @porphyrin but also Cl has lone pairs